# Timeout Error while connecting server and client in python

Tags: python, sockets, networking, websocket, pycharm

I used this on the server side:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.bind((socket.gethostname(),9999))
mysock.listen(1)
while True:
    clt, addr = mysock.accept()
    print('Connection request from', addr, 'was successfully established')
    clt.send('Connected to XYZ'.encode())
    clt.send('Closing connection, byee'.encode())
    clt.close()
```

and this on the client side:

```
import socket

mysock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
mysock.connect(("my ip",9999))        #will put ip of server

while True:
    msg = mysock.recv(1024)
    if len(msg) < 1:
        break
    mystring = msg.decode()
    print(mystring)
```

Here in when the client side script is run it produces the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\91829\Blogo> & C:/Users/91829/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/python.exe c:/Users/91829/Desktop/uu.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:/Users/91829/Desktop/uu.py", line 4, in <module>
    mysock.connect(("my ip",9999))
TimeoutError: [WinError 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond
PS C:\Users\91829\Blogo>
```

NOTE: In this the server and the host are different machines. the server is the local host i.e. my machine and the client is ,my friend's machine

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are they on the same network? They may not be able to connect directly without configuring intermediate networking gear. (do you know they can connect normally?)

Comment: Yes we both are on the same wifi

Comment: Can you share a directory with `python -m http.server` to test connecting? The flow of even a humble packet is quite complex, so tracing where the breakdown happens is key. Binding may not happen correctly, perhaps set host tuple member of `socket.bind` to `""` as in [this example from the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#example). Presumably the error is not simply forgetting to change the IP field from the string `"my ip"`?